# os module (opening folder)

Tags: python, module, directory, operating-system

I want to open the folder with the `os` module, but I can not do it,
because the `os` module can not recognize space (" ").

This is my path: `C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder`

And this is the error: `The system cannot find the file C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New.`

As you can see, the system can not recognize the space between (New) and (folder) and can not open the correct directory.

What should I do?

This is my code:

```
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

def open_folder():
    os.system(f"start {path}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use quotes

```py
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

def open_folder():
    os.system(f"start \"{path}\"")
```